# Whether captcha (or reCAPTCHA) is good or bad

Tags: web-application, ddos, captcha

I know captcha/reCAPTCHA is good to prevent spam posts as bots normally cannot bypass the challenges given by captcha/reCAPTCHA and thereby prevents bots submitting forms automatically.

Suppose there is a site in which only logged in users are able to submit the form. This reduces the risk of arbitrary form submission. But still a user can login, get session and make use of bots for form submission. So, here also  captcha/reCAPTCHA can help.

I am developing a website and was wondering how captcha/reCAPTCHA can help still in terms of performance.

for example, even if we use captcha/reCAPTCHA, the form submission still happens *(unless use captcha gets validated in javascript which does not make any sense)* and the server need to communicate to captcha provider (or process internally). So, if somebody is flooding the system with multiple requests, effectively the server load may be higher than in case of submission without captcha *(even if database processing is involved)*

Similarly even if somebody wants to flood the server and bring it down, multiple requests can be fired on a page which fetched data from db (may be using different ips) and still bring down the server. i.e., this may not give any protection from a determined attacker.

So why captcha/reCAPTCHA is used and how it is helping us in reducing server load. Please answer in the context of using captcha/reCAPTCHA and not in terms of using any other methods. Probably a better use of captcha/reCAPTCHA is in the login form to prevent brute force attack or to prevent spam bots making entries in databases using form submission. But this may not increase the performance in any way. Am i right here?

My knowledge in programming is limited and this may be a silly question. But I am not able to clear doubt even after lot of reading and hence posting this question here. thanks.

Comment: I think this answer pretty much answers all of your questions: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/22930/149676

Comment: hi, i had gone through that post also. but there is no definite answer for my questions. some say it can reduce ddos and some say it cannot.

Comment: @ConorMancone Hmm, that post doesn't appear too much up-to-date, though and it might not be an exact duplicate.

Comment: I don't think re-asking the same question is going to fix that problem for you.  That being said, I personally agree with the second answer there: CAPTCHAs provide little protection against DDoS.  They do protect against drive-by-posting-bots, but provide very little protection against more tailored attacks.  IMO, there are much simpler methods that work just as well, unless you are a target of particular interest.

Comment: @ConorMancone, thanks. can u please give any reference to the simple methods u mentioned.

Comment: Well, it makes perfect sense to use a CAPTCHA to rate-limit expensive computations. Likewise, mass registrations/comments/search queries/uploads can slow down a smaller site significantly. Nobody says that it helps withstand a full-blown DDoS, but there are definitely valid applications.