# What is the purpose of the temu captchas?

Tags: captcha, e-commerce

When shopping on temu, while logged in to an account for which temu has a credit card and physical address and browsing normally, I am presented by an slider CAPTCHA frequently enough that it is irritating.

From a search here, it seems [a use of CAPTCHAs is DoS protection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22906/how-does-captcha-mitigate-ddos-attacks), but that is "bad" and also me being logged in seems to preclude that.

Another potential use would be to protect their prices from competitors scraping their site.  From a search [it seems slider CAPTCHAs were defeated in 2018](https://doi.org/10.1145/3270101.3270104) ([available here](https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10095517)) with 96% - 100% success rate, by a group that defeated multiple different types of CAPTCHA and just got a conference paper out of it, and the description of their method takes less than a page.  I do not really know, but it does not seem likely that defeating this would be a major challenge for an organisation that could challenge temu considering the advances in AI over those five years.

As I understand it temu is losing loads of money to get customers at the moment in a fairly extreme example of blitzscaling.  It seems they would not put such an irritating feature into their web site without a very good reason.

What reason(s) could temu have for putting this CAPTCHA on their site?